# array_udiff seems not work

Tags: php, arrays, array-difference

I'm trying to compare two array with array_udiff, but it's very weired. it seems array_udiff not get the right answer. Here is the [live demo](https://eval.in/796826). The result should be an empty array, but leave one element unfiltered out.

```
<?php

$string = '{
  "sakiniai": [

      {
        "Faktas": "A",
        "value": "true"
      },
      {
        "Faktas": "B",
        "value": "true"
      },
      {
        "Faktas": "A",
        "value": "false"
      }
  ]
}';

$sakiniais = json_decode($string, true)['sakiniai'];


$v = $sakiniais[0];
$arr[] = $v;
$v['value'] = $v['value'] == "true" ? "false" : "true";
$arr[] = $v;
var_dump($arr);
var_dump($sakiniais);


print_r(array_udiff($arr, $sakiniais, function($a, $b){
/*
var_dump($a);
var_dump($b);
var_dump($a == $b);
echo "\n\n\n";
*/
return $a == $b ? 0 : -1;}
));
```

the output

```
    array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Faktas"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["value"]=>
    string(4) "true"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Faktas"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["value"]=>
    string(5) "false"
  }
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Faktas"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["value"]=>
    string(4) "true"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Faktas"]=>
    string(1) "B"
    ["value"]=>
    string(4) "true"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Faktas"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["value"]=>
    string(5) "false"
  }
}
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Faktas] => A
            [value] => false
        )

)
```

Comment: Maybe you should describe what you are trying to achieve. I cannot find the original question that had this requirement

Comment: @RiggsFolly here I compare two array, all the elements of first array are in the second array, so the expected output should be an empty array. But the result array has one element.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that array_udiff is not performing the comparison between all values, and this seems to be caused by your compare function.

array_udiff() expects that the callable function is a real compare function, but you are returning always 0 and -1, but never 1.

Before doing its job, array_udiff() tries to order both arrays and remove duplicates too. If it can't rely on your comparison function, it can't perform all the needed comparison and some values are "jumped".

Look at all comments in [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php) expecially napcoder comment

> Note that the compare function is used also internally, to order the
>   arrays and choose which element compare against in the next round.
>
> If your compare function is not really comparing (ie. returns 0 if
>   elements are equals, 1 otherwise), you will receive an unexpected
>   result.

This is demonstrated looking at your arrays

$arr

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Faktas"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["value"]=>
    string(4) "true"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Faktas"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["value"]=>
    string(5) "false"
  }
}
```

and $sakiniais

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Faktas"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["value"]=>
    string(4) "true"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Faktas"]=>
    string(1) "B"
    ["value"]=>
    string(4) "true"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Faktas"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["value"]=>
    string(5) "false"
  }
}
```

You should expect all the combinations between the two arrays to be tested, but the tested combinations (below) doesn't include A-False vs. A-False

```
array(2) {
    ["Faktas"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["value"]=>
    string(4) "true"
}
array(2) {
    ["Faktas"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["value"]=>
    string(5) "false"
}
bool(false)



array(2) {
    ["Faktas"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["value"]=>
    string(4) "true"
}
array(2) {
    ["Faktas"]=>
    string(1) "B"
    ["value"]=>
    string(4) "true"
}
bool(false)



array(2) {
    ["Faktas"]=>
    string(1) "B"
    ["value"]=>
    string(4) "true"
}
array(2) {
    ["Faktas"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["value"]=>
    string(5) "false"
}
bool(false)



array(2) {
    ["Faktas"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["value"]=>
    string(4) "true"
}
array(2) {
    ["Faktas"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["value"]=>
    string(4) "true"
}
bool(true)



array(2) {
    ["Faktas"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["value"]=>
    string(4) "true"
}
array(2) {
    ["Faktas"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["value"]=>
    string(5) "false"
}
bool(false)



array(2) {
    ["Faktas"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["value"]=>
    string(5) "false"
}
array(2) {
    ["Faktas"]=>
    string(1) "B"
    ["value"]=>
    string(4) "true"
}
bool(false)
```

In the correct answer at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18092562/misunderstanding-the-behavior-of-array-udiff) there are some other useful insights on how array_udiff works

You can change your return statement like this

```
if ($a < $b) {
    return -1;
} elseif ($a > $b) {
    return 1;
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

(if you are wondering how two arrays can be compared for less/greater, have a look at [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), in the section "Comparison with Various Types" and the "Example #2 Transcription of standard array comparison" example)

Comment: yes, I also find array_udiff not compare all values.

Comment: I updated the answer. You have to implement a real comparison function (that can sort the array elements in an order that is reliable)

Comment: added an example on how you can refactor your comparison function

Answer (score 0):

Nothing strange, everything works as expected. Take a look at arrays comparing:

```
$arraysAreEqual = ($a == $b); // TRUE if $a and $b have the same key/value pairs.
$arraysAreEqual = ($a === $b); // TRUE if $a and $b have the same key/value pairs in the same order and of the same types.
```

so, $arr[0] == $sakiniai[0] is true, but $arr[1] == $sakiniai[2] is false and the output is $arr[1]

$arr

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Faktas"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["value"]=>
    string(4) "true"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Faktas"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["value"]=>
    string(5) "false"
  }
}
```

$sakiniai

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Faktas"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["value"]=>
    string(4) "true"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Faktas"]=>
    string(1) "B"
    ["value"]=>
    string(4) "true"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Faktas"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["value"]=>
    string(5) "false"
  }
}
```

result

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Faktas] => A
            [value] => false
        )

)
```

Comment: $arr[1] == $sakiniai[2] is false? why?

Comment: because keys are not the same 1 != 2

Comment: keys are not 1, 2, but Faktas and value

Comment: no, you are wrong. `array_udiff` is used to compute the diference between single dimension arrays, so if you're giving multiarrays as parameters, the function will take keys from first dimension. If you want to compare multiarrays, you should write your own function

Comment: have you seen my compare funciton in the array_udiff?  And here is the [manual](http://php.net/manual/zh/function.array-udiff.php)